# Overflow doesn't work in Opera 28

Tags: css, overflow, opera, opera-blink

Does anyone know why Opera doesn't use `overflow:hidden`?

Left is Opera, right is Firefox
[image]

**CSS:**

```
#ChatBig {
    width: 60%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#ChatMessages{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 498px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#ChatText{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Opera 9 and 10 require the prefixed version, `-o-text-overflow`.

Comment: No, sorry didnt fix it

Comment: I cannot even do -o-text-overflow:hidden; gives me and error.. invalid css value on hidden

Comment: This is not a complete example, but I'm curious, does it work correctly in Chrome 41?

Comment: It should... Chrome works with everything (except Flash player mouse controls).

Comment: I don't know what your HTML looks like, but if it's a bit like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3avu7roy/1/), it works fine in Opera 28.

Comment: @KawineshSK that would be about the text-overflow property. This question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate your problem? As far as I can tell, it should work fine. @MrLister's example works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```css
#ChatBig {
    width: 60%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#ChatMessages{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 498px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#ChatText{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ChatBig">
    <div id="ChatMessage">
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        A line of chat<br/>
        ...
    </div>
    <textarea id="ChatText">
    </textarea>
</div>
```